# How can I ignore an incoming bluetooth connection/pairing request? Major Android Flaw

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

I accidentally tried to pair with a mystery bluetooth device from somewhere in the neighborhood awhile back, confusing it with a device I was trying to pair with. Now every time I turn on bluetooth in my house I get a pairing request from a mystery device. The neighbors don't know anything about bluetooth devices and I would feel weird going through their home looking for devices (plus that's really inappropriate). Can I get android to ignore this pairing request or is this a bug in android? If so, it seems like a serious flaw in the android OS itself. It's driving me nuts. I would pay money to stop this from happening. I use a Samsung Galaxy S5 with android 6.0. My next step is to reset my phone and see if that helps. I can't believe google left this big of a flaw in the android os that you can't block things when they spam you via bluetooth.

Just an update as of 8-23-2016. This looks to be a flaw in Android. I just wiped my phone completely and set it back up and the mystery device is still spamming my phone with connection requests and there is no way to stop it.

Comment: You're saying that device is requesting to pair with you? Because that's not your fault, that's just sketchy.

Comment: Yes, I turn on Bluetooth every day and get a pairing requests from this device every few seconds. It goes away when I get away from the condo. The requests are non stop

Comment: I would try contacting Samsung support, or your carrier. This could be fixed by a factory wipe, but there's really no telling. I've never heard of an issue like this.

Comment: Just did a factory wipe on my phone and when I turn on bluetooth the device is still spamming me every two or three seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think it's not your phone, but the other device. When you tried to pair with it, it remembered that (I can almost tell for sure you did not only try, you *succeeded* to pair with it). So now, when the other device sees yours in range, it automatically fires up request to pair. That's how Bluetooth works, and that's why the protocol is so convenient.

Check if this thread works for you:
[Ignore / stop incoming bluetooth connect/pair requests](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66909/ignore-stop-incoming-bluetooth-connect-pair-requests)

Comment: Yeah, Android really needs an ignore list for incoming bluetooth requests

Comment: The OP question is really about suppressing the pairing request: you can't control the other side.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out it was the bluetooth on my CPAP machine. I installed an add-on unit to my cpap machine for phillips respironics dreammapper. The device was named pr bt bf0d. The code for that is 1008. Android should have a feature where it can add and remove devices to a bluetooth ignore pair request list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same pairing request problem. I thought my Android Galaxy S5 was trying to pair with my Plantronics Back Fit PR BT 9A8D bluetooth device. I kept getting a pairing request for Plantronics PR BT 9A8D. The device was turned off and unpaired but I kept getting the request.
Apparently my Galaxy S5 was seeing my bluetooth Dreammapper on my CPAP machine.  Once I entered the CPAP code 1008. I was able to get my CPAP data and the pairing request stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I've been told that if you pair to the device that is asking to pair with you from *another* device (not your phone), then it will stop spamming your phone.

Just make sure the other device isn't one that will normally be in range of the spamming BT source, otherwise you'll just get the notice elsewhere.

In my case, the spamming BT device (Uconnect in a Jeep) can't be connected to from any other device.  So I'm going to have to destroy it with a sledgehammer, once I found out where it's located.

Answer (score 0):

My problem with the constant pairing tries was related to the smartband app (fitpro). I erase all data, force stoped the app and it was sucessfull.