# Unknown Bluetooth pairing requests

Tags: samsung, bluetooth-pairing

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 that is receiving unknown bluetooth pairing requests with a confirmation code every 60 seconds. I do not know what this device is, and I don't want to have to cancel these numerous requests. I use the bluetooth for my car and also my ASUS Zenwatch, so I don't want to have to turn off my Bluetooth all the time. My Bluetooth is only visible to paired devices, and this request from "Sparrow" does not show that it is one of my paired devices. I had my bluetooth turned off all weekend thinking it was something close to my house, but it has continued today even though I am not at home. Is there any way to block these requests without having to reset the whole phone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I ignore an incoming bluetooth connection/pairing request? Major Android Flaw](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/151958/how-can-i-ignore-an-incoming-bluetooth-connection-pairing-request-major-android)

Comment: Although it's kind-of the same question as the linked duplicate, I'm not voting to close because the other question was resolved by identifying the mystery device out-of-band.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem Sparrow is your Zenwatch