# Bluetooth constantly trying to pair

Tags: bluetooth, 8.0-oreo

I have a moto Z running android 8.  I have run into a problem where it is constantly trying to pair with a device that isn't present.  Like every 30 seconds or so I get a message that "pairing with *device mac* failed."  The only way I have found to stop it is to turn off bluetooth on the phone, which kinda defeats the purpose.  Doesn't matter where I am, home, work, in a park miles from the car, if bluetooth is turned on I am getting the popup.  Symptoms are similar to this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/151958/10192), but not location sensitive...

I have tried reboots, powering down for an extended period, forgetting all of my paired devices, and resetting network settings.  Still getting the popup.  I have had to clear it about 12 times in the course of typing this post...

Anyone have any idea what might be causing this to happen?

Comment: See if that happens in safe mode too. If it doesn't, it may be an app that is causing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like this was being caused by an app.  Doing a MAC look up on the device it kept trying to pair with indicated that it was manufactured by Weber-Stanley.  I have a bluetooth grill thermometer that they made, but it has been shut off and in a cabinet for a month or more, and definitely has not followed me to all the places where this has popped up.

Uninstalling the Weber app that works with it seems to have cleared up the issue.